# Error in optim in R: initial value cannot be infinite when calculating coefficients of probit model using MLE

Tags: r, mle

First I create a function to calculate individual probability and log-likelihood:

```
individual_probit <- function(mX, vBeta) {
        return (pnorm(mX %*% vBeta))
}

probitlikelihood <- function(vBeta,mX,vY){
        return (-sum(
          vY* log(individual_probit(mX, vBeta))+
            (1-vY)*log(1-individual_probit(mX, vBeta))
          )
          )
}
```

Then I input X, Y, and beta:

```
vY <- as.matrix(dta['Y']) 
mX <- as.matrix(data.frame(`(Intercept)`= 1,dta[c('A','B', 'C', 'D')])) 


vBeta0 = rep(0, ncol(mX))
```

Next, I want to use `optim` to estimate the maximum liklihood.

```
optimprobit <- optim(par = vBeta0,
                     fn = probitlikelihood,
                     mX = mX, vY = vY,
                     method = "BFGS",
                     hessian=TRUE,
                     control = list(maxit = 50000, trace = 2, REPORT = 1))
```

But the software told me that

> Error in optim(par = vBeta0, fn = probitlikelihood, mX = mX, vY = vY,  : initial value of 'vmmin' cannot be infinite.

I wonder why 'par=vBeta0' is wrong. Thank you!

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to calculate the log likelihood the way you did.  `pnorm` could give exact 0 or 1 values for extreme values of `mX %*% vBeta`, and then one of the logs will overflow, since `log(0)` gives `-Inf`.

Comment: we really need a [mcve] for this ... following up on @user2554330's comment, see `binomial(link="probit")$linkinv`